# Undefined reference to aruco functions

Tags: c++, opencv, aruco

I'm trying out the ArUco marker detection in a Qt GUI project and so far I keep getting the error message

```
undefined reference to cv::aruco::getPredefinedDictionary(cv::aruco::PREDEFINED_DICTIONARY_NAME)
```

I'm following the steps [here](https://docs.opencv.org/trunk/d5/dae/tutorial_aruco_detection.html)

I've tried making a fresh console project and copying the tutorial code from the ArUco module but all the aruco functions get undefined reference errors.

```
#include <opencv2/aruco.hpp>
...
using namespace cv;
using namespace std;
using namespace aruco;
...
Ptr<Dictionary> dictionary = getPredefinedDictionary(DICT_6X6_250);
```

Any help and/or advice would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer to my problem. As Mohammed-Foly mentioned, I needed to add the ArUco library. The answer was in the [second link he gave.](https://answers.opencv.org/question/199256/aruco-drawmarker/)

In the .pro file I simply added a line so it became something like this

```
INCLUDEPATH += "~/opencv-3.3.0/opencv/include"
INCLUDEPATH += "~/opencv-3.3.0/opencv/include/opencv"

LIBS += -L~/opencv-3.3.0/build/bin \
-lopencv_core \
-lopencv_highgui \
-lopencv_imgproc \
-lopencv_features2d \
-lopencv_calib3d \
-lopencv_video \
-lopencv_videoio \
-lopencv_aruco
```

Comment: Yes, the -lopencv_aruco do the Trick

Answer (score -1):

it seems that the problem is in the library linking, make sure you installed **aruco** library.

here is some links may be helpful
[Aruco tutorial code does not compile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36391657/aruco-tutorial-code-does-not-compile)
https://answers.opencv.org/question/199256/aruco-drawmarker/

Comment: @PraveenSP
my reputation is too low to add comment, so i had to ask in comment and same time i  added my probably right answer